# Integration and functions...

Tags: calculus

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function satisfying
$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx=\frac{1}{3}+\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(x^{2}\right)\right)^{2} dx,$ then find $f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried applying kings rule and formed another equation, subtracted both the equations to give  functional relation  . But I was unable to solve the equation to get f(1/4). Another approach   - took x^2=t and tried evaluating the integral but was unable to eliminate the constant term

Comment: Add your thoughts to your post to prevent closing and more downvotes.(:

Comment: A simple solution seems to be $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ giving $f(\frac14)=\frac12$ but  I do not see that this has to be the only solution

Comment: How did u arrive at the solution of f(x)

Comment: @karthikeyakurella, add your attempt to the post so the community members cand guide you, see what your difficulties are and help you. Otherwise, your question will be closed.

Comment: @barrycarter, you've comment my post once and it was really helpful. May I ask you, if you're willing, to help OP? I haven't covered this topic yet.

Comment: Echoing what others have said: when adding this kind of clarification that is essential to the post, please click on the tiny `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: change variables so the second integral involves $f(x)^2$ rather than $f(x^2)$.
Subtract right side from left, and complete the square in the integrand.